# Ruby Shoes and gems with native extensions

Tags: ruby, datamapper, shoes

Ruby. Shoes. DataMapper.
After an encoding error I get 'failed to build native extensions'.
That happens when I do the Shoes.setup and it tries to fetch and install the gem.

Since Shoes can't be run as a gem is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're wrong, shoes CAN be run as a gem, you have different flavors (colors) of shoes.
Most people work with Red Shoes but you also have a Green Shoes implementation, i use it always with native extensions. Not all methods from red are available and possibly you have to change your code a little but it should work. Success !

Comment: Well that is surprising.
The thing is that I'm developing on OSX 10.6 while my target platform is Windows 7. I'm trying to get green shoes up and running with little luck so far. I have also found a replacement that is Limelight on JRuby so I might just go with that because it will probably easier to port.

Comment: sudo gem install green_shoes
If problems, there is a very active community at http://librelist.com/browser/shoes/
You can subscribe their mailinglist.

Comment: limelight is interesting but there is almost no documentation nor examples, i found only a webcast creating a calculator.
Could you share your remarks about it ?

Comment: Yes there is very little documentation online with just that calculator and a broken link to a tutorial BUT there is pretty extensive and very newbie friendly tutorial in the program itself. If you run limelight without any options it would bring the main window with bunch of things one of which would be a full blown interactive tutorial. I'm still not sure if I'll go with that because limelight seems painfully slow.

Comment: I finally got green_shoes working. Could you give me some guidance on how to track down errors? There seems to be a bunch of those in the very little code that I've written in the regular Shoes. Green shoes is VERY unhelpful in finding out the causes of errors. It always tells me that the error occurred in a green_shoes internal files instead of mine. So it's basically blind debugging. But I guess that's the thing with these cute little DSL's. They aren't very useful if you can't separate your code.

Comment: look at http://ashbb.github.com/green_shoes/Red_Shoes_and_Green_Shoes.html
ashbb is also very helpfull in the mailinglist i described earlier, try it.
The following comes from http://shoesrb.com/manual/Built-in.html

debug(message: a string) » nil
Sends a debug message to the Shoes console. You can bring up the Shoes console by pressing Alt-/ on any Shoes window (or ⌘-/ on OS X.)
 debug("Running Shoes on " + RUBY_PLATFORM)

As we say, put your shoes on 8-)